# estimate and create zip files of specific size from a directory

Tags: python, zip

I am building a platform independant python-based tool which gives out a zip file at the end. The user has to then upload this zip file in our platform. Now we have a upload limit of 250mb for every user. Thus, in case the user's zip file > 250MB (which is possible and also acceptable) they cant upload. They have to then selectively choose their files and create numerous zip files within the upload limit and then upload them.

To ease the user's misery I wish to implement this function within the tool itself, i.e the tool should

1. dynamically zip the file in the directory
2. when the compressed file size reaches 250MB it creates a zip file e.g. zipfile_partn.zip (for the nth zip file of 250 MB
3. Ultimately the tool should have a bunch of zip files, each of 250mb (or less), that the user can then upload on our platform

I found this issue which is similar: [Python: Continuously check size of files being added to list, stop at size, zip list, continue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32763950/python-continuously-check-size-of-files-being-added-to-list-stop-at-size-zip)

```
import os,os.path, zipfile,time

#### Function to create zip file ####
# Add the files from the list to the zip archive
def zipFunction(zipList):
# Specify zip archive output location and file name
zipName = "O:\Exam Scan\exam-scan-ad_automate_input_pdf\pdfs\output.zip"
# Create the zip file object
zipA = zipfile.ZipFile(zipName, "w", allowZip64=True)  
# Go through the list and add files to the zip archive
for w in zipList:
    # Create the arcname parameter for the .write method. Otherwise  the zip file
    # mirrors the directory structure within the zip archive (annoying).
    arcname = w[len(root)+1:]
    # Write the files to a zip
    zipA.write(w, arcname, zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
# Close the zip process
zipA.close()
return

sTime = time.time()

# Set the size counter
totalSize = 0
# Create an empty list for adding files to count MB and make zip file
zipList = []
pdflist = []
xmlList = []

# Specify the directory to look at
searchDirectory = "O:\Exam Scan\exam-scan-ad_automate_input_pdf\pdfs"
# Create a counter to check number of files
count = 0

# Set the root, directory, and file name
for root,direc,f in os.walk(searchDirectory):
  print(searchDirectory)
  #Go through the files in directory
  for name in f:
      # Set the os.path file root and name
      full = os.path.join(root,name)
      # Split the file name from the file extension
      n, ext = os.path.splitext(name)
      # Get size of each file in directory, size is obtained in BYTES
      fileSize = os.path.getsize(full)
      # Add up the total sizes for all the files in the directory
      totalSize += fileSize
      # Convert from bytes to megabytes
            # 1 kilobyte = 1,024 bytes
            # 1 megabyte = 1,048,576 bytes
            # 1 gigabyte = 1,073,741,824 bytes
      megabytes = float(totalSize)/float(1048576)
      zipList.append(full)
      count +=1
      print(megabytes)
      if megabytes>5 :
          zipFunction(zipList)
          totalSize = 0
```

But here the approach is the total size of the files  when it reaches a limit, the code creates a zip. but I want this to be based on the zip size.

Answer (score 0):

I have used `zipfile` from python to create zip of give allowed size. We iterate over each file and write in zip, if zip size is equal or exceeds current file we are writing, we close it and create new zip file.

```
import os
import zipfile

# size is defined in mbs
def zip_folder(path, max_filesize=100):
    files_written = 1 # file counter
    zip_name = f"{files_written}.zip" # first zip filename
    zipWriter = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_name, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) # initialize zip writer
    zip_names = [f"{files_written}.zip"]
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            zipWriter.write(os.path.join(root, file), 
                       os.path.relpath(os.path.join(root, file), 
                                       os.path.join(path, '..')))
            
            # current zip size
            current_size = os.path.getsize(zip_name) >> 20
            if current_size > max_filesize: # if zip size increase allowed size
                zipWriter.close() # close current zip writer
                files_written += 1 # add increment
                zip_name = f"{files_written}.zip" # new zip name
                zip_names.append(zip_name) # add new filename to list
                
                zipWriter = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_name, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) # initialize writer

    return zip_names

zip_folder("path", 1024) # will create zip of 1GB each
```